# Draw polygon from point following streets in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, buffer

I'd like to draw an area around a certain point. I don't want a simple circle of 800 meters diameter, but a shape that is the result of the endpoints of lines, starting at my point and following all the roads it can find for 400 metres.

My available data is QGIS in version 2.14.13, a csv layer with those points and all kind of OSM layers.

I tried the approach to 1) label the points incl a background image and to 2) draw a larger icon with 800 map units in diameter (see Image).[image] That is roughly ok but not what I want it to be in the end

Any idea how to do that? I guess that I'd need to have the streets as a vector layer, so I would have to extract them within the are of 400 meters around my points, right?

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve, please? A picture of your data with some annotations or markups would probably help to understand your question.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: Edited the question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a network analysis (using your roads, OD matrice), you could make an isochronal map (now available in QGIS 2.99)

If you only want extract the endpoints using an euclidiean distance (buffer), I propose to do this :

1. Create a shapefile containing the **start_point** (origin)
2. Do a simple **buffer** from this point (distance = **800m**)
3. Extract by a **spatial query** the features that are **within**  the circle
4. Add the spatial query result to your map (temporary file)
5. Use the **v.to.points** tool (processing toolbox) without any change
6. Your points are created into a temporary file (default)

Be careful : you will get as many points as lines found at the start point.

I hope it's gonna be ok...

Comment: Thank you for the approach. If I enter 800m distance, I get a fullscreen colored layer. I chose my points layer as source, chose the buffer from the geoprocessing toos and entered the number. Didnt work.

The currently published QGIS version is 2.18.14 - what is the 2.99 about?

Comment: Your version is a good version, no problem about that. I think you're not following the differents steps I proposed. Your buffer must be a 800m radius circle, no more. If you zoom out, you must see your circle. If your radius circle is not correct, check your projection, It may be the problem you have. Good luck !

Comment: I already have a shape file, containing 48 starting points. When I open the vector layer -> geoprocessing ->buffer menu, I have more options than just "distance".

Comment: "Buffer distance" = 800m; the other parameters can stay by default exept if you want : make your buffer from specific points (check only selected features), make your buffer with differents distances (Buffer distance by a field), make as many buffer as points (dissolve buffer results).